# how to not display an element if empty in xml from .net LINQ to XML from datatable

Tags: xml, linq

I am trying to not display an element if it is empty in XML. I have the below code

```
XDocument doc =  new XDocument(
                new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes"),
                new XElement("products", 
                    from p in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                    select new XElement("ORDER",
                        new XElement("TYPE", p["LetterType"]),
                        new XElement("SUBTYPE", p["LetterSubType"]),
                        new XElement("ID_1", p["ID1"]),
                        new XElement("ID_2", p["ID2"]),
                        new XElement("ID_3", p["ID3"]),
                        new XElement("STATUS_DETAIL",
                            new XElement("STATUS", p["Status"]),
                            new XElement("STATUS_DATE", p["StatusDate"]),
                            new XElement("LANGUAGE", p["Language"])))));
```

The XML comes up as below

```
<ORDER>
    <TYPE>XYZ</TYPE>
    <SUBTYPE>ABC</SUBTYPE>
    <ID_1>ID123456</ID_1>
    <ID_2></ID_2>
    <ID_3></ID_3>
    <STATUS_DETAIL>
      <STATUS>N</STATUS>
      <STATUS_DATE>2014-08-04T13:37:54.33</STATUS_DATE>
      <LANGUAGE>01</LANGUAGE>
    </STATUS_DETAIL>
  </ORDER>
```

I don't want ID_2, ID_3 to be displayed in the XML because they are empty. How can I achieve that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a simple check before adding the XElement:

```
XDocument doc =  new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes"),
        new XElement("products", 
            from p in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
            select new XElement("ORDER",
                new XElement("TYPE", p["LetterType"]),
                new XElement("SUBTYPE", p["LetterSubType"]),
                !String.IsNullOrEmpty(p["ID1"].ToString()) ? new XElement("ID_1", p["ID1"]) : null,
                !String.IsNullOrEmpty(p["ID2"].ToString()) ? new XElement("ID_2", p["ID2"]) : null,
                !String.IsNullOrEmpty(p["ID3"].ToString()) ? new XElement("ID_3", p["ID3"]) : null,
                new XElement("STATUS_DETAIL",
                    new XElement("STATUS", p["Status"]),
                    new XElement("STATUS_DATE", p["StatusDate"]),
                    new XElement("LANGUAGE", p["Language"])))));
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. White. That was simple. One small correction. I had to swap the null and the data element in the check. Otherwise, it worked like a charm.

Comment: Ah, you're right, good point! I've added an exclamation mark in my code to switch it around...